# multiple textboxes in input prompt WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

coding4fun toolkit's input prompt has one textbox but I can't find any way to add another!
Here is the sample I found from google:

```
InputPrompt input = new InputPrompt();
        input.Completed += new EventHandler<PopUpEventArgs<string, PopUpResult>>(input_Completed);
        input.Title = "Test Title";
        input.Message = "Test message !";                        
        input.InputScope = new InputScope { Names = { new InputScopeName() { NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.EmailSmtpAddress } } };            
        input.Show();
```

Here i can add only single inputscope...but i need to add multiple text boxes here!
can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Coding4Fun control does not support this. You'll need to create your own control for such an interface.  (hint. You could extend the code of the C4F control.)

My understanding and expectation of the C4F control is that it was intended for quickly gathering an single piece of information which wouldn't warrant the need for its own page.
If you're looking to require the user to enter data into "multiple text boxes" you'll likely be able to create a better user experience (and one that is like the native apps on the phone) if you use a separate page to gather such information.

Comment: Thank you so much! i was thinking about it too....it would better to take those input in a separate page.